# Return a normal array from an array of promises - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a Text object every 1 second that will contain certain data. The data is returned in an array but the function is asynchronous.

I can't seem to get it working without expo complaining...

here's my code (I was messing about with it so a lot of this is just dummy stuff):

```
class TimeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { time: Date.now(), results: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.interval = setInterval(() => this.setState({ time: Date.now(), results: retrieveData().then(),
        do: Promise.all(retrieveData()).then(([x, y, z, a]) => {this.setState({results: })}) }), 1000);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.getStartedContainer}>
        {<Text>{this.state.do}</Text>}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and my async function

```
async function retrieveData() {
  let data = await C.all();
  var generalInfoArray = [data.c, data.d, data.r, data.a];
  return generalInfoArray;
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to return an array instead of a promise! You should revise your code and try to find another solution to the main problem.

Comment: Ok, so what's the alternative to achieve what i want?

Comment: Why don't you wait for promises to resolve and then try to change the component state by `this.setState`?

Comment: Ok... but i'm very new to React and not sure how i can change my code to do that...

Comment: where would i write code to wait for promises to resolve?

Comment: `componentDidMount() {
  this.interval = setInterval(
   () => {
    retrieveData()
     .then(data => {
      this.setState({
       time: Date.now(),
       results: data,
       // ... 
      })
     });
   },
   1000
  );
 }`

Comment: omg thank you so much that worked!!!

Comment: can you post it as an answer Ehsan so i can mark it as an answer?

Comment: you're welcome! I will post the code as an answer.

Comment: something like forkJoin , switchMap form rxjs will return resolved promises for you in native js promise.all()

Comment: @HasanDaghash could you provide an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the state of the component after the promise get resolved.

```
componentDidMount() { 
  this.interval = setInterval( 
      () => { 
        retrieveData() 
         .then(data => { 
            this.setState({ 
               time: Date.now(), 
               results: data, 
               // ... 
             }) 
          }); 
       }, 
       1000 
    ); 
 }
```